# Session variable in c#?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to have something similar to a web session in c#?

For example if I set a integer somewhere `integer id = 5;` Could I access that integer at a later time in a different class?

I am writing an app that communicates with a web service and I need to keep the id of the authenticated user around for queries to the web.

Or is my best option to use a database and store the id and access it from the database when needed.

Comment: `integer id = 5;` does not make or set a `string`. (It also doesn't compile in C#.)

Comment: Classes can have properties, and properties can hold data.  Object Oriented Design allows for the passing of objects through your application.  If you just want some big global variable, thats available too, but not recommended.

Comment: What's wrong with having a class that represents your connection to the web service? That class could hold the id.

Comment: You could create a dedicated session object that represents your session and pass that along where needed.

Comment: @paqogomez available where?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Im trying to avoid passing it around everywhere. Just stores in memory somewhere that I can access at any time.

Comment: There are two problems you are describing in your question and it is not clear which you want solved. Do you want a place to store `id` so after you close and re-open your program it remembers the value, or do you want a single global location you can ask for information and you can get the result from any class in your program?

Comment: @Deekor `available where?` - in the language itself. A `static class` with `public static` properties is probably what @paqogomez meant. I would definitely recommend against that, given your skill level and the debugging nightmare "global variables" like that can introduce. You should invest your time in learning more about OO design and structure.

Comment: It's one thing to say you "want to access it at any time" but you're not envisioning correctly how that has to be filled in. Yes, you could make a `static` class that holds that for you but global state is considered an anti-patten for a reason. What makes you not want to pass it around as an argument?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The app is an iOS app and there are so many classes and controllers that need the id that I'm just trying to simplify it up a bit.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead That actually worked perfect for what I needed.

Comment: @Deekor: for your own sake, don't go with the `static` route. You will guaranteed run into problems if you ever decide to create tests and it is a dangerous trend to start. If you're really bent on adding global state to your application then you should do as a conscious decision because alternatives are not feasible.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel how expensive is reading and writing a text file? Just seems like a lot to get a simple id.

Comment: @Deekor: I highly doubt you'd notice any impact, but now ask yourself the question: how do you read and write to that text file from every place where you need that? Will you write `File.ReadAllLines()` every time? Maybe you'll factor it out into another class? Now you're stuck again with choosing between a `static` class and a non-static one.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel so thats not a better idea?

Comment: No, because you end up with the same situation except now you'll serialize it to the filesystem every time instead of just keeping it as a property. You'll still have to pass the class around. Frankly it might not be a bad idea to just do it the way you think you would do it because it'll show you where that approach goes wrong exactly.  Global state is bad for testing because it becomes hard to control and will interfere with the isolated aspect of unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

Simply enough.

No need for a database. If the only thing that needs to persist is a simple ID, you can save it in a binary file, xml file or plain text.

The best equivalent to session variables I can think of is :

- Right click on your project
- Click on properties
- Click on settings
- Set you variable there by selecting the type, the name, the scope of the variable (Application or User) and set the value

By the way, the C# type is `int`